# call keySet() with SharedPreferences.getAll()

Tags: android, dictionary, call, sharedpreferences, keyset

I am new to both Java and Android so hopefully my question will make sense (I think I know what I am asking!)

I am working my way through an example in a book and I have a query with the following statement:

```
String[] tags = savedSearches.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Where savedSearches is a SharedPreferences Object.

`savedSearches.getAll()` returns a Map which allows the call to `KeySet()` to be made.  What I am failing to understand is how the `KeySet()` call is possible.  I am under the impression that if you are going to be using a class/Interface in your code then you need to import it or import a class/Interface which directly or Indirectly extends/implements the object making the call, in this case a reference to a Map.

The example I am working on imports the following:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
```

I have had a look at the Java and Android API and I can’t see that a Map is implemented in any of the above (unless I have missed it!) so in principle I should not be able to make a call to `KeySet()`.  So how is it possible to make this call to `KeySet()`?

Hopefully the above will make some sort of sense :/  Any help or pointers in the right direction to help me understand this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keySet()` is a method that returns a set of all the keys of the `Map(public Set<K> keySet ())`. So, methods are not to be imported. Though Map is not imported but the return type of `getAll()` method is `Map<String, ?>` so it can be directly accessed.

If you fetch `getAll()` seperately like,

```
Map<String, ?> map = preferences.getAll();
```

Then you will have Map imported else you can directly access it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understand.  Because you are returning a map reference through getAll() and then calling keySet() on that you can then use the keySet() with out having to import the Map class, unlike the situation you pointed out where returning getAll() directly to a defined map object would require the import of the Map class.